# How can I keep a button centered on the page and responsive?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am trying to make it so that the button that I have centered on the screen (when the screen is full size, it is centered) stays in the center while still scaling down to fit to smaller screens.

I have tried some of the answers I found here and other places about changing `position: absolute;` and wrapping the button in a div with `text-align: center;` and `margin: auto;` but so far the button ends up not staying centered.

Here is what I have:

```
    .wrapper {
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
  }

  #mybutton {
  position: absolute;
  left: 37%;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  bottom: 10%;
  letter-spacing: .55rem;
  max-width: 50%;
  background: #3498db;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3498db, #2980b9);
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #666666;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-color: #3498db;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

This is probably something very simple that I am missing, but it's late and I am tired of messing around with this, so if anyone can offer any help, it would be appreciated!

Comment: Show your markup please

Comment: try to use bootstrap.

Comment: @AmiteshKumar there's no need to add a giant library like Bootstrap when OP just wants to center an element responsively.

Comment: @Parker try this https://jsfiddle.net/8vcgejc2/  you just need width and text-align

Comment: yes i know but i think if he asking for button responsive then he will also need responsive page or website. so i suggested him

Comment: @ChoncholMahmud "markup" being the html?

Comment: @AmiteshKumar, responsive doesn't mean bootstrap only. and user will be confused if he will read whole bs to just center one button. Comments for help not for confusion. bt thanx for help.

Comment: @Leothelion Works beautifully! Knew it would be something simple. Thank you so much!

Comment: ok posting as answer . plz accept. Thanx

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
  position: relative;
}

button {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <button>CLICK ME</button>
</body>
```

[see my pen for further explanation](http://codepen.io/skyfire/pen/JGKVoQ) on how I used transform property of css

Answer (score 0):

Make it simple. You just need `text-align:center` with width.

**CSS i have used**

```
width:50%;margin:0 auto;text-align:center;
```

see [here](https://jsfiddle.net/8vcgejc2/)

Answer (score 0):

try this , it is working .

```
.button1 {
  text-align: center;
}
.button1 a {
  background-color: #03326c;
  font-size: 25px;
  height: 35px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  padding: .5em 1em;
}

<div class="button1">
  <a href="" title="title"><span class="Button1">BUTTON</span></a>
or you can put button also.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I understood of your problem: you wanted to make a button that scaled in accordance with the screen size **AND** you wanted it to be be centered.

I've pretty much done what you've been trying to do and achieved [this](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dGXLPP).

```
.wrapper{
    text-align: center;
}

button{
  width: 50%;
  ...
}
```

Assigned the text align center property to the button's parent div and assigned the button a relative width.